# Android Location update

Tags: android, location

Im writing an android aplication in which is required the actual location of the user, but I'm having trouble acquiring that location.

I'm using a LocationListener to listen for the location update, via Wifi (NETWORK_PROVIDER). 
The problem is I don't get an update, and I imagine it only happens when I change network. If I don't get updates, I can use lastKnowLocation but it does not provide me with the actual user's location.

Is there a way to force a location update, via NETWORK_PROVIDER?

Cheers

Comment: if you haven't already seen [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) check it out. It covers exactly what you're asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better, I suggest you look at the new Location APIs in Google Play Services.

There's a [training class](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) for them as well.