# Show GPS location in Real time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Goal:
The coordinate should display at the screen in real time without pressing the button.

Problem:
In order to display the current location from the gps you have to press the button.
Is it possible to display the value in the screen in realtime without pressing the button?

Info:
*The foundation of the source code is from this [page](http://www.exceptionbound.com/programming-tut/android-tutorial/get-current-gps-location-in-android).
*Today, Im newbie in android
*This code retrieve gps coordinate from the gps hardware and not from the google maps API.

Thank you!

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfdimarzio.test_gps_1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="exceptionbound.com.gpslocation.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Coordinates: "
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Request Location" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

MainActivity

```
package com.jfdimarzio.test_gps_1;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };


        configure_button();
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode,
            @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 10:
                configure_button();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    void configure_button()
    {
        // first check for permissions
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                        , 10);
            }

            return;
        }
        // this code won'textView execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //noinspection MissingPermission
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listener);
            }
        });
    }




}
```

Comment: In `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, if you got permission, call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: How, do you have a sample. It is easier to understand. Im still new in android. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Location update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303399/android-location-update)

Comment: Not the same because  it retrieve api from google map. The source code I have is not  API from google map

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html . Exactly the same.

Comment: I have read about the link that you have provided. When I have read the content I still don't know how to solve it in order to achive the goal. It feels that the purpose of the content is not enough to solve the case.