# Does it Create a new database in every time when you run the app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

Based on these tutorial about creating a database in android in relation to SQLite.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2rL3sAFmI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8TaTgr4uKM

My question is:
WHen you run this app and it creates a new database and you save some data. However when you rerun the application, does it create a new database again? What would be happened to the previous saved data? will they be removed?

Today Im a newbie in android

Thank you!

Comment: Please add code, think no one is interested to watch a whole youtube movie to understand your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) will call the different lifecycle methods based on the `version` number that you pass in via its constructor.  It will compare the *last* version number that you passed in.

`SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate` is called *only* when there is no database available that the location specified.  This is where you create your tables.

`SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade` is called *only* when there is a database available and the version number is higher than the previous version number.  This is where you will do SQL operations to update the database tables to what they should be for the new schema.  Most tutorials generally show a clear tables operation and a manual call to `onCreate()`. If you do that, then you will wipe the entire database every time you upgrade it (if you increase the version number).

`SQLiteOpenHelper#onDowngrade` is called *only* when there is a database available and the version number is lower than the previous version number.  Similar to `onUpgrade`, this is where you would do SQL operations to revert the tables to what they should be.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If you are interrested and have time have time, please go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520081/show-gps-location-in-real-time